# What is the best tool for creating a Java extension?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, parsing, lexer

Our project group is working on a Java language extension and we have been trying to figure out what tool we should use for this purpose. The extension will primarily consist of a modification of the concurrency model used in Java. We have been looking at two tools so far: Polyglot and Javacc. Javacc seems to be a bit more easy to use, but as we will be making some significant changes to the language it might still not be a good idea to use it over the more advanced Polyglot as it might be better at coping with the increased complexity.

Do you have any experience with these tools and/or do you have other tool recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org) is a very good choice.  It's a bit more active than JavaCC, and the documentation is better.  There's a book available on Amazon that you'll find to be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Check [Jetbrain's MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/index.html), but I have no experiences with it so far.

Comment: MPS is a great tool for creating and extending languages, not only Java-based. It is exactly matching tool if you need to 'rewrite' some parts of Java language or standard libraries.
You should _definetely_ spend a week learning their system (including Actors framework) before creating your own java extentions.

Comment: @Alex do you work for Jetbrains ?